# Quicklisp using sbcl: getting UNDEFINED-FUNCTION error when loading various libraries

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

I'm trying to use quicklisp with SBCL 1.0.55.0.debian on xubuntu. So far, it's been slow going. About half of the time, I can load a library with, e.g., `(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")`.

But the other half of the time, I'm getting this error instead (while trying to load hunchentoot-cgi, libxml2, and a few others):

```
The function :NICKNAMES is undefined.
[Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

I've tried all of the restarts except for 2 (accept). This happens both in emacs/SLIME and at the REPL. I don't know exactly where the source file for, say, 'sb-kernel' is, but I'm not sure I'd even know how to fix it if I did. Any suggestions?

(UPDATE: The line `(:use :cl)` was directly below the `(:nicknames :alexandria)` line in `package.lisp`; swapping their places fixed the problem, but I'm curious as to how it got that way in the first place.)

The full trace (for hunchentoot-cgi) is:

```
The function :NICKNAMES is undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]

Restarts:
 0: [TRY-RECOMPILING] Recompile package and try loading it again
 1: [RETRY] Retry loading FASL for #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "alexandria" "package">.
 2: [ACCEPT] Continue, treating loading FASL for #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "alexandria" "package"> as having been successful.
 3: [ABORT] Give up on "hunchentoot-cgi"
 4: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 5: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 --more--

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-KERNEL:%COERCE-CALLABLE-TO-FUN :NICKNAMES)
  1: (SB-FASL::FOP-FUNCALL)
  2: (SB-FASL::LOAD-FASL-GROUP ..)
  3: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-RECURSIVE-LOCK-THUNK :IN SB-FASL::LOAD-AS-FASL))
  4: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-88923 :IN SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-RECURSIVE-LOCK))
  5: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-RECURSIVE-LOCK ..)
  6: (SB-FASL::LOAD-AS-FASL ..)
  7: ((FLET SB-FASL::LOAD-STREAM :IN LOAD) ..)
  8: (LOAD ..)
  9: (SB-IMPL::%MAP-FOR-EFFECT-ARITY-1 ..)
 10: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD ASDF:PERFORM (ASDF:LOAD-OP ASDF:CL-SOURCE-FILE)) ..)
 11: ((SB-PCL::EMF ASDF:PERFORM) #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument> #<ASDF:LOAD-OP (:VERBOSE NIL) {10ABFD01}> #<ASDF:CL-SOURCE-FILE "alexandria" "package">)
 12: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD ASDF::PERFORM-WITH-RESTARTS (ASDF:LOAD-OP ASDF:CL-SOURCE-FILE)) ..)
 13: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD ASDF::PERFORM-WITH-RESTARTS :AROUND (T T)) ..)
 14: ((LAMBDA () :IN ASDF::PERFORM-PLAN))
 15: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-RECURSIVE-LOCK-THUNK :IN SB-C::%WITH-COMPILATION-UNIT))
 16: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-88923 :IN SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-RECURSIVE-LOCK))
 17: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-RECURSIVE-LOCK ..)
 18: ((FLET SB-C::WITH-IT :IN SB-C::%WITH-COMPILATION-UNIT))
 19: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD ASDF::PERFORM-PLAN (LIST)) ..)
 20: ((LAMBDA () :IN ASDF:OPERATE))
 21: (ASDF::CALL-WITH-SYSTEM-DEFINITIONS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN ASDF:OPERATE) {108EF07D}>)
 22: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD ASDF:OPERATE (T T)) #<unused argument> #<unused argument> ASDF:LOAD-OP "hunchentoot-cgi" :VERBOSE NIL)
 23: ((SB-PCL::EMF ASDF:OPERATE) #<unused argument> #<unused argument> ASDF:LOAD-OP "hunchentoot-cgi" :VERBOSE NIL)
 24: (QUICKLISP-CLIENT::CALL-WITH-MACROEXPAND-PROGRESS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT::APPLY-LOAD-STRATEGY) {108EEE4D}>)
 25: (QUICKLISP-CLIENT::AUTOLOAD-SYSTEM-AND-DEPENDENCIES "hunchentoot-cgi" :PROMPT NIL)
 26: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD QL-IMPL-UTIL::%CALL-WITH-QUIET-COMPILATION (T T)) ..)
 27: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD QL-IMPL-UTIL::%CALL-WITH-QUIET-COMPILATION :AROUND (QL-IMPL:SBCL T)) ..)
 28: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD (T)) #<unused argument> #<unused argument> #<unavailable argument> :PROMPT NIL :VERBOSE NIL)
 29: (QL-DIST::CALL-WITH-CONSISTENT-DISTS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD) {108CD455}>)
 30: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD "hunchentoot-cgi") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 31: (EVAL (QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD "hunchentoot-cgi"))
 32: (SWANK::EVAL-REGION "(ql:quickload \"hunchentoot-cgi\")\n")
 33: ((LAMBDA () :IN SWANK::REPL-EVAL))
 34: (SWANK::TRACK-PACKAGE #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN SWANK::REPL-EVAL) {108CD12D}>)
 35: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-RETRY-RESTART "Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request." #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN SWANK::REPL-EVAL) {108CD0BD}>)
 36: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BUFFER-SYNTAX NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN SWANK::REPL-EVAL) {108CD0A5}>)
 37: (SWANK::REPL-EVAL "(ql:quickload \"hunchentoot-cgi\")\n")
 38: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (SWANK:LISTENER-EVAL "(ql:quickload \"hunchentoot-cgi\")\n") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 39: (EVAL (SWANK:LISTENER-EVAL "(ql:quickload \"hunchentoot-cgi\")\n"))
 40: (SWANK:EVAL-FOR-EMACS (SWANK:LISTENER-EVAL "(ql:quickload \"hunchentoot-cgi\")\n") "COMMON-LISP-USER" 144)
 41: (SWANK::PROCESS-REQUESTS NIL)
 42: ((LAMBDA () :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 43: ((LAMBDA () :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 44: (SWANK-BACKEND::CALL-WITH-BREAK-HOOK #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {D2420C5}>)
 45: ((FLET SWANK-BACKEND:CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK :IN "/home/amperry/.emacs.d/slime-2.7/swank-sbcl.lisp") #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {D2420C5}>)
 46: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BINDINGS ..)
 47: (SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS #<SWANK::MULTITHREADED-CONNECTION {CBAE9B1}> NIL)
 48: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-223578 :IN SB-THREAD:MAKE-THREAD))
 49: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD:MAKE-THREAD))
 50: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-88894 :IN SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX))
 51: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX ..)
 52: (SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION)
 53: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp")
 54: ("foreign function: funcall0")
 55: ("foreign function: new_thread_trampoline")
 56: ("foreign function: #xB7FA6D4C")
```

Comment: I hesitate to chime in since I'm new to Common Lisp, but it looks like you're having a problem with the Alexandria package, which is probably a dependency.  Is it installed and/or can you reinstall it?

Comment: The error comes from the `package.lisp` file of `alexandria`. That file begins with `(defpackage :alexandria.0.dev (:nicknames :alexandria) ...`; my guess is that the first line is either missing or corrupted, leading the compiler to interpret the second line as a function call to `:nicknames`. Check that file; it's located in the path `~/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/alexandria-20130128-git/` or something like that.

Comment: That kind of error happens when (defpackage foo (:nicknames bar)) is evaluated when the active package does not use CL. In that case it reads as SOMEPACKAGE::DEFPACKAGE, is treated as a function, and it tries to evaluate the arguments per a normal function call.

Comment: SBCL maintainers thought it was a good idea to introduce an incompatibility with common practice (though not the standard): packages by default don't inherit from the CL package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Xach pointed out, the active package did not `(:use :cl)` by the time `(:nicknames :alexandria)` was called. Swapping the order of those two lines fixed the issue, although I have no idea why they were in that sequence to begin with.